# Find model instances that contain associated models whose length is > n

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline

Given some models like this:

**User**

```
{
    attributes: {
        report: {
            collection: "report",
            via: "owner"
        }
    }
}
```

**Report**

```
{
    attributes: {
        owner: {
            model: "user"
        }
    }
}
```

Can I write a query in a single line that will return an array of users that contain more than 0 reports?

```
User.find({ 
    report: {">": 0} 
}).exec(function(err, result) {
    res.send(result);
});
```

It's easy to do with `async.map` but I wanted to know if it's possible to avoid having to `async.map` your initial result array. Having gone through the [docs](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/query-language) it doesn't seem like this is possible?